Redirecting output to $null in PowerShell, but ensuring the variable remains set with ForEach-Object -Parallel
I have this code:
$Newarr | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
Start-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -Name $_.Name
}    

$Newarr contains a set of data that I don't want to print as output, but which I obviously need for the function. How do I make it not print anything, but keep the info for the function?
I tried with | out-null and >&null after -Parallel, but it doesn't work:
($Newarr | ForEach-Object -Parallel) | Out-Null {
Start-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -Name $_.Name
}    


what do you mean by "it doesn't work" ?

There will not be the output of the $Newarr array, but the command between
'Start-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $.ResourceGroupName -Name $.Name' will not go.

please update your question showing how you're using >&null and | Out-Null

done, I don't know of course if it's right to put it like that

you have a typo, thats not how Out-Null is used. $Newarr | ForEach-Object -Parallel { Start-AzVm .... } | Out-Null

so it doesn't print the one inside the {}, I would need something that doesn't print the array, but prints the one inside

its unclear what you mean then

Then $Newarr is an array of Azure resources, with all the related fields. I don't need it to print all the fields for each resource in $Newarr. The problem is that when I do "$Newarr | ForEach-Object -Parallel" (only useful for doing the Start command inside) the script prints me every field of every resource. I'm assuming that this printing is for the "$Newarr" command, so I'd need something that doesn't make me print it, but is still valued for the function between {}. I hope this is clear.

So do you mean that you want each VM to be started (i.e. $_ having a value inside the braces) and no output to be generated when you run it?

Yes for the first part. Each VM needs to be started, but I need the output of the Start-AzVm command. While I don't need the output of the command "$Newarr | ForEach-Object -Parallel" which is very long.

The only command I can see that is generating any output in your sample is Start-AzVm - can you show a concrete example of the output you’re seeing and the output you want instead (just show the output for a single vm, not your entire dataset).

As you deduced in the comments, the output is from the Start-AzVm cmdlet.
You need to suppress the output of THAT cmdlet, not the Foreach-Object
There are multiple ways to do this: piping to Out-Null, redirecting to $null, assigning to $Null, casting as [void].
In Powershell Core/7.4.x they are more or less equivalent
But in Powershell Desktop/5.1 there are SENSIBLE differences in performance: redirecting to $null is generally the most efficient.
Plus: redirecting lets you redirect ONLY the Success Stream(if you want), so you can display the other Output Streams, Error and Warning Stream especially.
Thus I suggest to use it unless there are other necessities.
Implementation is pretty simple, too
$Newarr | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Start-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -Name $_.Name 1>$null
} 

remove or change the 1 to change which Stream is redirected.
(I suddenly have the doubt that if nothing is specified only the Success Stream is redirect, but being explicit is not going to hurt)
also, have a but of code I used to test the efficiency of the various methods
$n = 1000
$Measures = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{Method = "| OutNull"  ; AverageTime = 1..$n | Measure-Command { $(1..$n) | Out-Null } | Measure-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average }
    [pscustomobject]@{Method = "[void]" ; AverageTime = 1..$n | Measure-Command { [Void]$(1..$n) }  | Measure-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average }
    [pscustomobject]@{Method = '> $Null' ; AverageTime = 1..$n | Measure-Command { $(1..$n) > $null }  | Measure-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average }
    [pscustomobject]@{Method = '1> $Null' ; AverageTime = 1..$n | Measure-Command { $(1..$n) 1> $null }  | Measure-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average }
    [pscustomobject]@{Method = '$Null =' ; AverageTime = 1..$n | Measure-Command { $null = $(1..$n) }  | Measure-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average }
    [pscustomobject]@{Method = "Control Value" ; AverageTime = 1..$n | Measure-Command { $(1..$n) }  | Measure-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average }
)

$Measures | Sort-Object -Property AverageTime

